# substituir id por nome

Tags: php, mysql

Bom galera eu tenho uma tabela chamada venda e nessa tabela eu insiro alguns dados de outra tabela ate ai tudo blz , o meu problema e na hora de mostrar esses dados quando eu do um echo na tela não aparece o nome do produto mas sim o id dele e eu preciso que apareça o nome , esse e meu código :

```
<?php
include("banco.php");
echo'<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/estilo.css">';
echo'<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">';
echo '<a href="vendas.php" style="color: #ffffff" class="btn btn-inverse">Cadastrar Vendas</a></br></br>';

 include("banco.php");

        $id = $_GET["id"];

        $sql = mysql_query("select * from venda where id_venda='$id'");

        $exibe = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);

        $perfil=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM venda WHERE id_venda='$id'");

        $dados=list($id_venda,$venda,$data,$placa,$km,$produtos,$servicos)=mysql_fetch_row($perfil);


?>
<label for="nome" style="color: #000"><strong>ID DA VENDA :</strong> </label>
<input type="text" readonly="true" name="id" value="<?php echo $dados[0]; ?>">
<label for="nome"readonly="true" style="color: #000"><strong>Nº DA VENDA:</strong> </label>
<input type="text" name="id" readonly="true" value="<?php echo $dados[1]; ?>">

<div id="camp1">

<label for="nome" style="color: #000"><strong>DATA :</strong> </label>
<input type="text" name="id" readonly="true" value="<?php echo $dados[2]; ?>">
<label for="nome" style="color: #000"><strong>PLACA :</strong> </label>
    <input type="text" name="id" readonly="true" value="<?php echo $dados[3]; ?>">
</div>


<div id="camp2">
<label for="nome" style="color: #000"><strong>KM :</strong> </label>
<input type="text" name="id" readonly="true" value="<?php echo $dados[4]; ?>">
<label for="nome" style="color: #000"><strong>PRODUTO :</strong> </label>
<input type="text" name="id" readonly="true" value="<?php echo $dados[5]; ?>">
</div>

<div id="camp3">
<label for="nome" style="color: #000"><strong>SERVIÇO :</strong> </label>
<input type="text" name="id" readonly="true" value="<?php echo $dados[6]; ?>">
</div>
```

Eu usava o seguinte codigo para fazer a transformação de id para o nome , mais como eu nao estou listando os items nao funciona :

```
 $produtos = "SELECT * FROM produtos WHERE id=". $dados['produtos'];
    $query = mysql_query($produtos);
    $b=mysql_fetch_array($query);
    #$id = $b ['id'];
    $produtos = $b ['produtos'];
```

Aonde esta **Produto** e **Serviço** que eu Gostaria que aparecesse o nome e nao o id :

[image: mostra]

Comment: Primeiro você tem que se certificar que na tabela venda existem os campos com os nomes do serviço e do produto. Caso contrário você deverá fazer um join nas tabelas que tenham esses nomes. Uma boa prática também é sempre trazer somente os campos que você irá utilizar, ao invés de usar o *.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você poderia fazer um join na tabela de produtos para obter a informação ou utilizar a ideia do código abaixo para fazer a conversão na propria tela:

```
 $produtos = "SELECT * FROM produtos WHERE id=". $dados[5];
    $query = mysql_query($produtos);
    $b=mysql_fetch_array($query);
    #$id = $b ['id'];
    $produtos = $b ['produtos'];
```

Comment: Fiz umas pequenas edições e deu certinho , muito obrigado mano ;)

Answer (score 0):

Quando fizer uma consulta e dois ou mais tabelas tem informações relacionadas faça um join para pegar as informações de todas e não várias consultas.
Um detalhe importante, caso os campos tenham nomes iguais use um alias para evitar que uma chave do array mostre um valor incorreto.

```
    $id = isset($_GET["id"]) && ctype_digit($_GET['id']);
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM venda as v
                     INNER JOIN produtos as p ON v.id_produto = p.id_produto
            WHERE v.id_venda='$id'";
    $sql = mysql_query($sql);
    $registro = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);
```

Para exibir os valores no form faça dessa forma, não é preciso utilizar `list()` ou outras variáveis.

```
<input type="text" readonly="true" name="id" value="<?php echo $registro['id']; ?>">
```